# Running correlation (gtools)

Tags: r, csv

I am an R newbie, trying to do simple things.
I wanted to examine the running correlation between two time series (two CSV files).
Below is my code, after loading the gtools package:

```
v1<-read.csv("var1.csv", header = FALSE)

v2<-read.csv("var2.csv", header = FALSE)

running(v1,v2,fun=cor, width=5)
```

I receive the following error message:
***named list()***

Then I try again by assigning first a variable:

```
p1<-running(v1,v2,fun=cor, width=5)

plot(p1)
```

I receive the following error message:

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :    'x' is a list, but
>   does not have components 'x' and 'y'

What am I missing?

How can I create a plot that shows the running correlation and the line that represents the 95% confidence interval?

Thanks!

`v1` and `v2` are as follows:

```
v1 = structure(list(var1 = c(-0.888829723, -0.638363898, -0.820331055, -0.711637919, -3.631666745, 0.528082315, -0.888551728, 3.670203445, -0.406498322, 1.185030346, 1.427746793, -0.393369446, 2.905055593, -0.401353407, -0.563123881, 1.140042632, 7.078661195, 2.556181809, 0.888551728, -3.670203445, 0.406498322, -1.185030346, -1.427746793, 0.393369446, -2.016225871, 1.039717305, 1.383454936, -0.428404714, -3.44699445, -3.084264124)), .Names = "var1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))

v2 = structure(list(var2 = c(0.008871463, -0.218818955, 1.055065334, 1.353131909, -1.021284981, -2.153524661, 1.825212612, 0.460388983, 1.48721711, -1.78249802, 0.46047233, -0.894777526, -0.852226438, 0.136373161, -0.248409748, -0.411183561, 0.912205699, -1.856740048, -1.825212612, -0.460388983, -1.48721711, 1.78249802, -0.46047233, 0.894777526, 0.843354976, 0.082445794, -0.806655586, -0.941948347, 0.109079282, 4.010264709)), .Names = "var2", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

Comment: what do your `var1` and `var2` csv files contain?

Comment: var1 and var2 are time series for temperature anomalies.

Comment: I meant what is the structure: how many columns/rows, etc.

Comment: Each file has only one column.

Comment: One column and 30 rows (each representing one year). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you want to run 5 year rolling correlation and your given period is 1988-2017 (30 years):

```
v1<-read.csv("var1.csv", header = FALSE)
v2<-read.csv("var2.csv", header = FALSE)

v1 = structure(list(var1 = c(-0.888829723, -0.638363898, -0.820331055, -0.711637919, -3.631666745, 0.528082315, -0.888551728, 3.670203445, -0.406498322, 1.185030346, 1.427746793, -0.393369446, 2.905055593, -0.401353407, -0.563123881, 1.140042632, 7.078661195, 2.556181809, 0.888551728, -3.670203445, 0.406498322, -1.185030346, -1.427746793, 0.393369446, -2.016225871, 1.039717305, 1.383454936, -0.428404714, -3.44699445, -3.084264124)), .Names = "var1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
v1 = as.vector(v1$var1)
v2 = structure(list(var2 = c(0.008871463, -0.218818955, 1.055065334, 1.353131909, -1.021284981, -2.153524661, 1.825212612, 0.460388983, 1.48721711, -1.78249802, 0.46047233, -0.894777526, -0.852226438, 0.136373161, -0.248409748, -0.411183561, 0.912205699, -1.856740048, -1.825212612, -0.460388983, -1.48721711, 1.78249802, -0.46047233, 0.894777526, 0.843354976, 0.082445794, -0.806655586, -0.941948347, 0.109079282, 4.010264709)), .Names = "var2", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
v2 = as.vector(v2$var2)

rc <- running(v1, v2, fun = cor, width = 5)
length(rc)
plot((2017-length(rc) + 1):2017, rc, type="l")
```

This should give you the rolling correlation plot.

Comment: After entering this line:
  
> rc <- running(var1, var2, fun = cor, width = 5)
    
I receive the following error message:
    
Error in running(var1, var2, fun = cor, width = 5) : 
  object 'var1' not found

Comment: The script works up to 'length(rc)' (which returns a value of 0).  
 
Then when the plot line of code is entered, it gives the following error message:   
 
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Comment: Can you post `dput(v1)` and `dput(v2)` results here?

Comment: structure(list(var1 = c(-0.888829723, -0.638363898, -0.820331055, 
-0.711637919, -3.631666745, 0.528082315, -0.888551728, 3.670203445, 
-0.406498322, 1.185030346, 1.427746793, -0.393369446, 2.905055593, 
-0.401353407, -0.563123881, 1.140042632, 7.078661195, 2.556181809, 
0.888551728, -3.670203445, 0.406498322, -1.185030346, -1.427746793, 
0.393369446, -2.016225871, 1.039717305, 1.383454936, -0.428404714, 
-3.44699445, -3.084264124)), .Names = "var1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))

Comment: structure(list(var2 = c(0.008871463, -0.218818955, 1.055065334, 
1.353131909, -1.021284981, -2.153524661, 1.825212612, 0.460388983, 
1.48721711, -1.78249802, 0.46047233, -0.894777526, -0.852226438, 
0.136373161, -0.248409748, -0.411183561, 0.912205699, -1.856740048, 
-1.825212612, -0.460388983, -1.48721711, 1.78249802, -0.46047233, 
0.894777526, 0.843354976, 0.082445794, -0.806655586, -0.941948347, 
0.109079282, 4.010264709)), .Names = "var2", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))

Comment: Try now. If you provided the data in your initial post, this would have been much simple.

Comment: I am new in the forum. How do I do that (upvote)? Thanks.

Comment: Ha! You cannot upvote unless you have more than 15 points (you have only 1). But you can `accept` my answer by clicking on the `check` mark, which will also give you 2 points.

Comment: Done! Once again, Thanks a lot!